# Flutter package notification_listener_service works only in debug mode

Tags: java, android, flutter, notifications, notificationlistenerservice

I'm using this package `notification_listener_service` on flutter for reading the notifications on android device.

It works in debug, but when I make the release with `flutter build apk --release` it doesn't listen to the notifications, neither if I build it with `flutter build apk --debug`

I gave permission in the AndroidManifest:

```
<service
        android:label="notifications"
        android:name="notification.listener.service.NotificationListener"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

And the code is this:

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:notification_listener_service/notification_event.dart';
import 'package:notification_listener_service/notification_listener_service.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: HomePage(),
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    debugShowMaterialGrid: false,
  ));
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  bool havePermission = false;
  String errorMessage = "";
  final List<ServiceNotificationEvent> events = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("INIT STATE");
    checkPermission();
  }

  Future<void> checkPermission() async {
    /// check if notification permission is enabled
    bool status = await NotificationListenerService.isPermissionGranted();

    /// if permission listen notifications
    if (status) listen();

    havePermission = status;
    setState(() {});
  }

  Future<void> listen() async {
    try {
      print("LISTEN");
      NotificationListenerService.notificationsStream.listen((event) {
        print("NEW EVENT: ");
        print(event);

        events.add(event);
        setState(() {});
      });
    } catch (e) {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100));
      errorMessage = e.toString();
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  Future<void> sendReply(ServiceNotificationEvent event) async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));

    print(event.packageName?.contains("telegram"));

    if (event.packageName?.contains("telegram") ?? false) {
      final msg = ["ciaooo", "Come va?", "Sono una AI replier"];
      event.sendReply(msg[Random().nextInt(3)]);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Escort Reply Messages'),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(32),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text("Permission added: ${havePermission ? "Yes" : "No"}"),
              SizedBox(height: 32),
              Text("Error: ${errorMessage.isNotEmpty}"),
              Text(
                errorMessage,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 32),
              Text("Your notification"),
              ListView.separated(
                itemCount: events.length,
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 32),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                separatorBuilder: (_, i) => Divider(color: Colors.black),
                itemBuilder: (_, i) => Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Text(
                        "packageName: ${events[i].packageName}\ntitle: ${events[i].title}\ncontent: ${events[i].content}\ncanReply: ${events[i].canReply}",
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When I'm running it in debug it works, I gave permission to read notifications on my android device, the listener start, when I receive a notification is successfully added to the list of notifications and showed in the list.

But in release the listener doesn't start, and I don't have any error, every time I receive a notification it doesn't added to the list of notifications.

Somebody can help me?

Comment: Did you add the permission in the correct AndroidManifest?

Comment: @OzanTaskiran Yes I did, in the /android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml